# Xcode 5 showing "splash screen missing" even if it is present in the project bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5.1

I have added 7 splash screens (3 for iPhone and 4 for iPad) in total into Xcode project. To be more clear, I have added below splash screens into the Xcode Resources --> splash folder.

```
Default-568h@2x.png
Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
Default-Landscape~ipad.png
Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
Default-Portrait~ipad.png
Default.png
Default@2x.png
```

But when I open my project in Xcode, it is showing below warning.

[image]

Does someone know why this is happening. I am new to Xcode 5 and thus don't know much regarding this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Select the image in Xcode navigator and in the utilities area check the target membership. check if you have you added them to your project or not..

Comment: Have you checked if there is any issue with resolutions?

Comment: @Pooja: I quickly checked the resolution of the splash screens which I added for iPad. Below are the resolutions of the four splash screens that I have for iPad:   1024 × 768, 2048 × 1536, 1536 × 2048, 768 × 1024

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick Try to clean your project and quit Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

You just create different size for slash screen. Ex: 768x1004, etc.

Xcode will automatically show different image for different device (iPhone, iPad retina or not)

Comment: Do you mean that I have to add new images with all those resolutions which Xcode is complaining ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. When you release in app store, sure to have different users with different devices (iPhone-4,4S,5,5s, iPad etc), xCode will display the image which you set here.

Comment: If you look into the warnings that xcode is showing, you can see that it's saying 8 images are missing. But, I am having already having 4 of them in my bundle. How is it asking for those also?

Comment: If I include all the 8 splash screens for iPad, what about their naming convention.

Comment: Whatever name. Ex: 768x1004.png, 1024x748.png. It's OK

Comment: I will try and let you know.